# Php script signup form that creates a new database for each new user

Tags: php, mysql, database, amazon-web-services

I need to make a Signup page for a web app i am making and upon registrering the script will create a new database for the user on my webhost (Amazon ASW) does anyone know how to make a simple PHP script that takes the value and add them to a database that is predefined?

Comment: It requires learning and researching dude, you can't go to Google and ask for a "simple" pair of Google Glasses

Comment: Where to begin! First of all, in 99.99% of cases, you don't want to make a fresh database for each user. There are plenty of examples online of how to insert a record into a DB using a form. Try something and come back with error messages so people here can help you. Show some effort, no-one will want to code the whole thing for you.

Comment: @Jodes he is referring to the method that web hosting companies use, to give them complete access to their own isolated database which the can use as they want